# Docker build: is the content from a layer keep on the next one?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to Dockerize [PyroCMS](https://pyrocms.com) and this is how my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM reynierpm/docker-centos7-supervisord:latest
ENV TERM=xterm \
    PATH="/root/.composer/vendor/bin:${PATH}" \
    COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 \
    COMPOSER_ALLOW_XDEBUG=1 \
    COMPOSER_DISABLE_XDEBUG_WARN=1 \
    COMPOSER_HOME="/root/.composer" \
    COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR="/root/.composer/cache"

RUN yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
                   https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
RUN yum install -y  \
        yum-utils \
        git \
        zip \
        unzip \
        wget \
        nano \
        php71-php-fpm \
        php71-php-cli \
        php71-php-common \
        php71-php-gd \
        php71-php-intl \
        php71-php-json \
        php71-php-mbstring \
        php71-php-mcrypt \
        php71-php-mysqlnd \
        php71-php-pdo \
        php71-php-pear \
        php71-php-xml \
        php71-php-pecl-xdebug \
        php71-pecl-apcu \
        php71-php-pecl-apfd \
        php71-php-pecl-memcache \
        php71-php-pecl-memcached \
        php71-php-pecl-mongodb \
        php71-php-pecl-redis \
        php71-php-pecl-request \
        php71-php-pecl-uploadprogress \
        php71-php-pecl-xattr \
        php71-php-pecl-zip && \
        yum clean all && rm -rf /tmp/yum*
RUN ln -sfF /opt/remi/php71/enable /etc/profile.d/php71-paths.sh && \
    ln -sfF /opt/remi/php71/root/usr/bin/{pear,pecl,phar,php,php-cgi,phpize} /usr/local/bin/. && \
    mv -f /etc/opt/remi/php71/php.ini /etc/php.ini && \
    ln -sfF /etc/php.ini /etc/opt/remi/php71/php.ini && \
    rm -rf /etc/php.d && \
    mv /etc/opt/remi/php71/php.d /etc/. && \
    ln -sfF /etc/php.d /etc/opt/remi/php71/php.d

RUN /bin/sh -c "mkdir -p /data/www" && \
    /bin/sh -c "mkdir -p /data/php/{tmp,sessions,xdebug,logs,uploads}" && \
    rm -rf /data/www/*
COPY container-files /
WORKDIR /data/www
RUN sh /usr/local/bin/composer-install.sh
RUN git clone --branch 3.2 https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms.git .
COPY .env .
RUN pwd && ls -la
RUN php artisan install --ready
RUN chmod +x /config/bootstrap.sh
EXPOSE 9005
```

This is a WIP so don't bother with optimization or so on since I don't care about it at this moment.

For build the image I am running `docker build -t reynierpm/pyrocms .` which goes smooth until reaches this step:

```
RUN php artisan install --ready
```

where it fails with the following error:

```
Step 14/16 : RUN php artisan install --ready
 ---> Running in ffbddd585ef1
Could not open input file: artisan
The command '/bin/sh -c php artisan install --ready' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but this is what I have so far:

- `WORKDIR /data/www` will keep all my work from now on at `/data/www` unless I change it to another dir which I am not doing at any point
- `RUN git clone --branch 3.2 https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms.git .` clones properly the repository branch since doing a `ls -la` just right after the command shows me the following output:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 .
  drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 ..
  drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 .git
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root   12 Jan 26 16:50 .gitattributes
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root   97 Jan 26 16:50 .gitignore
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root 2254 Jan 26 16:50 CONTRIBUTING.md
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  556 Jan 26 16:50 Gulpfile.js
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root 1088 Jan 26 16:50 LICENSE.md
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root  236 Jan 26 16:50 README.md
  drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 addons
  drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 app
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1646 Jan 26 16:50 artisan
  drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 bootstrap
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root 1525 Jan 26 16:50 build.xml
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root 3708 Jan 26 16:50 composer.json
  drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 config
  drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 core
  drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 database
  drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 docs
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  400 Jan 26 16:50 package.json
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1397 Jan 26 16:50 phpunit.xml
  drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 public
  drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 resources
  drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 routes
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  560 Jan 26 16:50 server.php
  drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 storage
  drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 tests
  drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:50 tmp
  ```
- `COPY .env .` will copy the file `.env` to `/data/www` (but if the syntax is wrong already tried with `COPY .env /data/www/.env`)

After run the steps above I should end up with the content from the clone and also `.dev` in addition but it's odd since I end up with only this:

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:54 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  337 Jan 26 15:39 .env
```

And of course this make the build to fail since the file `artisan` is not there anymore.

Why? Should not the files be keep between layers? Any ideas?

Comment: tried removing the `.` (dot) at the end of the `RUN git clone [...]` line?

Comment: @WebertS.Lima if I remove the `.` it will clone in a `pyrocms` subdirectory which I don't want to.

Comment: oh I see. As you can see, docker outputs each layer ID in the form `---> Running in ffbddd585ef1`. You can try to `docker exec -ti XXXX bash` where `XXXX` is the ID of the `RUN git clone [...] part, and then run this command manually. See what happens.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima I can't the container isn't running at all, it stops during build with the error as in the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just pulled the `reynierpm/docker-centos7-supervisord:latest` image on my machine, and the `/data` location in that image is a volume.

```
$ docker inspect reynierpm/docker-centos7-supervisord:latest
...
        "Volumes": {
            "/data": {}
        },
...
```

Each step in the build is run as a container. Since `/data` is a volume specified by an image, each step will have a new, blank, anonymous volume at /data. When the build step finishes, the changes to that container's copy-on-write system are committed as the next layer. Since any changes to `/data` are in the volume and not in the COW filesystem, they are not included in the commit.

To get around this, make sure you ADD or COPY files to a location that is not a volume in the base image you are using.